# How to connect via jdbc to Amazon RDS with sslmode= require?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jdbc, amazon-redshift

I know that Amazon have [sslmode](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-ssl-support.html)=require for ODBC driver. but

I didn't find such mode for [jdbc driver](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-options.html). How can I specify  sslmode= require  for JDBC.

The same question for default and prefer mode.

Answer (score 1):

You specify sslMode and/or ssl on your jdbc string
as per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-options.html

e.g. add &sslMode=verify-ca&ssl=true to your connection string

Comment: But it's not the same mode,  sslmode=require for ODBC is not a &sslMode=verify-ca&ssl=true for jdbc. What the difference between ;sslMode=verify-ca;ssl=true and use & instance ;?